# Firebase database retreiving value, is this possible

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code:

```
DatabaseReference mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("allmessages");
        mdatabase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(userID).child(uploadID).push().setValue("somevalue");
```

Then in another class I have this code:

```
DatabaseReference mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("allmessages");
 mdatabase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Loop through all files in Uploads DataBase
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                AllChatMessagesGet allChatMessagesGet = postSnapshot.getValue(AllChatMessagesGet.class);
```

is it possible for me to get all value under `mdatabase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(userID).child(uploadID).push().setValue("somevalue");` by the code I used above.

Because it doesn't retrieve me anything back. I thought that the above code in `addValueEventListener` would go trough all child classes of `mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()` and retrive me the "somevalue".

But it doesn't. So how do I retrieve "somevalue". Is there any other way? because the codes are written in different classes and I dont know how to get `.Child(userID)` and `.Child(uploadID)` it would be problematic for me.

is there anyway for me to retrive all childrens of `mdatabase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())` and their values that exist some `child` below it.

[image: Database Structure]

Comment: Please add your database structure and idicate the data that you want to get.

Comment: I have added image of the database structure

Comment: You are asking: "Is there anyway for me to retrive all childrens of `mdatabase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())` and their values (**which values?**) that exist some child below (**which child?**) it.". Please indicate the exact value that you want to get.

Comment: okay sorry if I wasn't clear. The 2 childs of AllChatMessages are userUid. I want to call `mdatabase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())`, and somehow get the value of the childs that starts with LD6. Which is equal to "somevalue" in `mdatabase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(userID).child(uploadID).push().setValue("somevalue");`

Comment: There is a way but to understand better, "get the value of the childs that starts with LD6" what does it mean? you want a list off all those ids just by calling `mdatabase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())`?

Comment: yes all those that starts with LD6 under LCzWNw0nlC3GKsnPH8B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments, to get those ids that starts with `-LD` under `-LCzWNw0nlC3GKsnPH8B` node using only `rootRef.child("AllChatMessages").child(uid)`, please use the followig code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("AllChatMessages").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : ds.getChildren()) {
                for(DataSnapshot snap : dSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String key = snap.getKey();
                    Log.d("TAG", key);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output will be all those ids that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Add and implement a `ChildEventListener` instead of a `ValueEventListener`.
Your "somevalue" should be in the DataSnapshot of the overriden `onChildChanged` method.

Comment: I copied my code from above and tried adding it in both onChildChanged and onChildAdded and neither worked, both returned null in the Log

Answer (score 0):

I have write up a code glimpse of it is in below code. What I was doing was getting value from the node of users. I have retracted all the children of it by the below code you may also try the same way maybe it would help you.

```
mFirebaseUserReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
 userReference = mFirebaseUserReference.child("Users");

        childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.d("Values",dataSnapshot+"");
                HashMap temp = (HashMap) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                if (temp!=null){
                    if (!temp.get("id").equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())){
                        SignInModel signInModel = new SignInModel();
                        signInModel.setPhotoUrl((String)temp.get("photoUrl"));
                        signInModel.setEmail((String)temp.get("email"));
                        signInModel.setName((String)temp.get("name"));
                        signInModel.setId((String)temp.get("id"));
                        arrayList.add(signInModel);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };

        userReference.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

Hope that helps.